# Creating RDS Instances from Snapshot Using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Working on a Terraform project in which I am creating an RDS cluster by grabbing and using the most recent production db snapshot:

```
# Get latest snapshot from production DB
data "aws_db_snapshot" "db_snapshot" {
    most_recent = true
    db_instance_identifier = "${var.db_instance_to_clone}"
}

#Create RDS instance from snapshot
resource "aws_db_instance" "primary" {
    identifier = "${var.app_name}-primary"
    snapshot_identifier = "${data.aws_db_snapshot.db_snapshot.id}"
    instance_class = "${var.instance_class}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_id}"]
    skip_final_snapshot = true
    final_snapshot_identifier = "snapshot"
    parameter_group_name = "${var.parameter_group_name}"
    publicly_accessible = true
    timeouts {
      create = "2h"
    }
}
```

The issue with this approach is that following runs of the terraform code (once another snapshot has been taken) want to re-create the primary RDS instance (and subsequently, the read replicas) with the latest snapshot of the DB. I was thinking something along the lines of a boolean count parameters that specifies first run, but setting `count = 0` on the snapshot resource causes issues with the snapshot_id parameters of the db resource. Likewise setting a `count = 0` on the db resource would indicate that it would destroy the db.

Use case for this is to be able to make changes to other aspects of the production infrastructure that this terraform plan manages without having to re-create the entire RDS cluster, which is a very time consuming resource to destroy/create.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try placing an `ignore_changes` lifecycle block within your `aws_db_instance` definition:

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      snapshot_identifier,
    ]
}
```

This will cause Terraform to only look for changes to the database's `snapshot_identifier` upon initial creation.

If the database already exists, Terraform will ignore any changes to the existing database's `snapshot_identifier` field -- even if a new snapshot has been created since then.

Comment: Since terraform `0.12` (May 2019), the double quotes around `snapshot_identifier` should be omitted. If running a terraform plan with the double quotes it will display the warning: `Warning: Quoted references are deprecated ... In this context, references are expected literally rather than in quotes. Terraform 0.11 and earlier required quotes, but quoted references are now deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Terraform. Remove the quotes surrounding this reference to silence this warning.`